# How to make your custom view focusable?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-custom-view

I am creating a custom view. This is basically a rectangle box with borders in it. I want the border to change color and make it focusable when a user clicks on it. I want the border to return to original color if the rectangle loses focus. I want to use this background as form background. I have tried android documentation and stack overflow answers and I am not able to do this. I have made it clickable but I am not able to proceed further than that.

```
public class FormBackgroundView extends View implements View.OnClickListener{

    private int _borderColor;
    Paint fillPaint, strokePaint;
    Canvas canvas;

    public FormBackgroundView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    public FormBackgroundView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    public FormBackgroundView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        init();
    }

    public FormBackgroundView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
        init();
    }

    private void init(){
        super.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        fillPaint = new Paint();
        strokePaint = new Paint();

        fillPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        fillPaint.setColor(Color.WHITE);

        strokePaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        strokePaint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        strokePaint.setAntiAlias(true);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP){
            canvas.drawRoundRect(0,0,getWidth(),getHeight(), 10, 10, strokePaint);
            canvas.drawRoundRect(0 + 3,0 + 3,getWidth() - 3,getHeight() - 3, 7, 7, fillPaint);
        } else {
            canvas.drawRect(0,0,getWidth(),getHeight(), strokePaint);
            canvas.drawRect(0 + 4,0 + 4,getWidth() -4 ,getHeight() -4, fillPaint);
        }

        this.canvas = canvas;
    }



    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

    }


}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Custom View not responding to touches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10406354/custom-view-not-responding-to-touches)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your view is not automatically focusable in touch mode. You must make a call to "setFocusableInTouchMode()` if you want your view to get the focus when it is clicked (touched.) Although dated, I found [this explanation](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2008/12/touch-mode.html) useful to describe touch mode.

So, in your `init()` add `setFocusableInTouchMode(true)`.

Secondly, you don't do anything different in your `onDraw()` whether the view is focused or not. Change it to something like the following:

```
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    // your paint code
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        if (isFocused()) { // draw the border
            canvas.drawRoundRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), 10, 10, strokePaint);
            canvas.drawRoundRect(0 + 3, 0 + 3, getWidth() - 3, getHeight() - 3, 7, 7, fillPaint);
        } else { // don't draw the border
            canvas.drawRoundRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), 7, 7, fillPaint);
        }
    } else {
        //similar here
    }
    // The rest of your code
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I want to ask one thing when is onDraw() is called. I thought it was called only one time. Is it being called again when focus changes?

Comment: or when invalidate() is called by us ?

Comment: @killerprince182 Yes it is called. For a focusable view, there is usually some visual indication that the view has focus, so it makes sense that `onDraw()` would be called.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
public class FormBackGroundView extends View {

    private int _borderColor;
    Paint fillPaint, strokePaint;
    Canvas canvas;
    private boolean isFocused;

    public FormBackGroundView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    public FormBackGroundView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    public FormBackGroundView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        fillPaint = new Paint();
        strokePaint = new Paint();
        fillPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        strokePaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        strokePaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
                if (motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN && !isFocused) {
                    isFocused = true;
                    invalidate();
                } else if (motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP && isFocused) {
                    isFocused = false;
                    invalidate();
                }
                return true;
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);


        fillPaint.setColor(Color.WHITE);

        strokePaint.setColor(isFocused? Color.RED:Color.BLACK);


        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            canvas.drawRoundRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), 10, 10, strokePaint);
            canvas.drawRoundRect(0 + 3, 0 + 3, getWidth() - 3, getHeight() - 3, 7, 7, fillPaint);
        } else {
            canvas.drawRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), strokePaint);
            canvas.drawRect(0 + 4, 0 + 4, getWidth() - 4, getHeight() - 4, fillPaint);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This code has one problem. Form returns to normal as soon as form is stopped touching.